# My buttons are blank(using modal, jquery)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

This is my script, where i set the text for the buttons.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            height: 150,
            buttons: [
                {
                    text: "Confirm",
                    click: function() {
                        window.location.href = targetUrl;
                    }
                },
                {
                    text: "Cancel",
                    click: function() {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }]
        });

        $(".deleteLink").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var targetUrl = $(this).attr("href");
            $("#dialog-confirm").dialog("open");
        });

    });
```

This is my html code

```
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Delete" > 
    <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert"></span>Are you sure you would want to delete?
</div>
```

Is anyone able to see whats wrong here? Im thinking it could be my css, but im using standard bootstrap, and i cant find anything wrong with it.

Edit: oh, and this is how the button looks like when i inspect it

```
<button type="button" text="Confirm"></button>
```

And heres a picture:
[image]

**End Edit:
So, it seems ui 1.8.22 of jquery dosn't work, but 1.8.23 does. how can that be?**

Comment: can you post a demo at jsfiddle.net so that we can work on it?

Answer (score 1):

Change button definition way:

```
$("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    height: 150,
    buttons: {
        "Confirm": function() {
            window.location.href = targetUrl;
        },
        Cancel: function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
```

Taken from [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form)

Comment: Can you create fiddle that reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 1):

To fix the buttons issue, change the script according to jQuery documentation or my sample bellow. In addition if you want to pass the targetUrl to the dialog, you could do it this way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".deleteLink").click(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        var targetUrl = $(this).attr("href");

        $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            height: 150,
            buttons: {
                "Confirm": function() {
                    window.location.href = targetUrl;
                },
                "Cancel": function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
});​
```

Comment: So, it seems ui 1.8.22 of jquery dosn't work, but 1.8.23 does. how can that be?